# joining lists of different length in R

Tags: r, append

I am not sure if R has the capabilities to do this, but I'd like to join two different lists of different lengths so that it's like a nested list within a list (if that makes sense).

edit:  I'd like to add values in x as an additional value in z.

```
z  <- c("a", "b", "c")
x <- c("c", "g")
c(z, x)
[1] "a" "b" "c" "c" "g"

# what I'd really like to see
[1] "a" "b" "c" "c, g"
```

I think it would be something similar to doing the following in python pandas

```
 self.z.append(x)
```

Comment: Why is that the first one 'z' not joined together?.  The examples showed are `vector`s and not `list`.   Can you create the nested list?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. z is a list of values. x is a list of values. I'd like to add values in x as an additional value in z. I'm not sure if R can handle this though?

Comment: I think you need `c(z, toString(x))` but because you mentioned about nested `list` and stuff, I am not sure

Comment: wow I have never come across toString() before. This seems to be only for character strings though? But good to know. Thank you.

Comment: It is just `paste(., collapse=", ")`  It can be used for numeric as well `toString(1:3)`, but the output will be `character` class

Comment: Besides akrun's suggestion, you might consider `c(z, list(x))` as a nested "list" to not convert to "character"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can `paste` the 'x' together and concatenate with 'z'

```
c(z, toString(x))
#[1] "a"    "b"    "c"    "c, g"
```

Comment: Thank you again akrun. Given that I've had this work in Python Pandas using append, I was trying to do the same with some "equivalent" in R (i.e., binds, etc.). I'll accept once the timer allows...

Comment: @user2340706  There is also `append` function in `R` which would be more flexible wrt to adding a new vector in a particular position. i..e. `append(z, toString(x), after=2)`

Comment: Thank you @akrun. That append() function actually serves better for this current problem.